# Deleted instance passed to merge, org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException, @ManyToOne root cause, Why?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee

The following function seems to be the root cause of a org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [com.zetorv.product.pid.model.ServerResponseOption#] when i request an option to be removed;

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "command", nullable=false)
public BasicMenuCommand getCommand() {
    return this.command;
}
```

But when i change the @ManyToOne line to just `@ManyToOne` removing the `(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})` part it works ok;

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "command", nullable=false)
public BasicMenuCommand getCommand() {
    return this.command;
}
```

Effectively the code that performs the save/update is: `return this.entityManager.merge(object);`

In general terms changing from `@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})` to `@ManyToOne` what effect does that have?

Comment: Please tell us in which class this property is, and the code that deletes and merges.

Comment: This class is com.zetorv.product.pid.model.ServerResponseOption and it's class def is: `    @XmlType
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "sysprod_server_response_option")
    public class ServerResponseOption implements Serializable`

Comment: Edit your question. We don't know which entities are involved and which code is executed when the exception is thrown.